# How to update CSV in each it blocks in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I want to update CSV file data (Ex: columns data like orderId, date etc...) in each **it** blocks of spec file.  I have written code to update CSV inside Cypress.config.js file and calling cy.task from spec file. But everytime first **it** block updated CSV is passed to all other **it** blocks. Please let me know how can I achieve this

Under uploadOrders.cy.js

```
/// <reference types='Cypress'/>

import { ORDERS } from '../../selector/orders';
import BU from '../../fixtures/BU.json';
import Helper from '../../e2e/utils/Helper';
const helper = new Helper();

let getTodaysDate = helper.getTodaysDate(); // get today's date and store in getTodaysDate variable
let getTomorrowssDate = helper.getTomorrowsDate(); // get tomorrows's date and store in getTomorrowssDate variable
let getYesterdaysDate = helper.getYesterdaysDate(); // get tomorrows's date and store in getTomorrowssDate variable



describe('Upload Orders', () => {
    // Before start executing all it blocks
    before(() => {
        cy.login(); //login code written in cypress commands.js file
        cy.get(ORDERS.ORDER_ICON).click();
    });

    // Before start executing each it block
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/finalCsvToBeUploaded.csv', ''); // clears the file before each it block executes

    });

// First it block
    it('Upload orders and check its successful', () => {
        let csvData = {
            orderId: 'OrderId_' + helper.getCurrentDateAndTimeInMiliseconds(),
            orderDate: getTomorrowssDate,
            homebaseExecutionDate: getTomorrowssDate,
            customerExecutionDate: getTomorrowssDate,
        }

        cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/referenceCsvFile.csv')
            .then((data) => {
                cy.task('csvToJson', data)
                    .then(finalJsonArray => {
                        cy.task('updateCsvData', { csvData, finalJsonArray })
                            .then(finalUpdatedJsonArray => {
                                cy.log("Update JSON array: " + finalUpdatedJsonArray[0]['Order ID']);
                                cy.task('finalCsv', finalUpdatedJsonArray);
                            });
                    })
            })
        cy.get(ORDERS.ORDER_UPLOAD).click();
        cy.attachCsvFile('finalCsvToBeUploaded.csv');
        cy.validateToastMsg('Orders uploaded successfully');
        cy.log('Order is uploaded successfully  via csv file and orderId is ');
    });

// Second it block
    it('Upload orders and check validation for past customer execution date', () => {
        cy.wait(5000);
        let csvData = {
            orderId: 'OrderId_' + helper.getCurrentDateAndTimeInMiliseconds(),
            orderDate: getTomorrowssDate,
            homebaseExecutionDate: getYesterdaysDate,
            customerExecutionDate: getYesterdaysDate,
        }
        cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/finalCsvToBeUploaded.csv')
            .then((data) => {
                cy.task('csvToJson', data)
                    .then(finalJsonArray => {
                        cy.task('updateCsvData', { csvData, finalJsonArray })
                            .then(finalUpdatedJsonArray => {
                                cy.log("Update JSON array: " + finalUpdatedJsonArray);
                                cy.task('finalCsv', finalUpdatedJsonArray);
                            });
                    })
            })
        cy.get(ORDERS.ORDER_UPLOAD).click();
        cy.attachCsvFile('finalCsvToBeUploaded.csv');
        cy.validateToastMsg('Orders uploaded successfully');
        cy.log('Order is uploaded successfully  via csv file and orderId is');
    });


    // After exection of all it blocks
    after(() => {
        // clear cookies and localStorage
        cy.clearCookies();
        cy.clearLocalStorage();
    });
});
```

Under cypress.config.js file

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const converter = require('json-2-csv');
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const { default: Helper } = require("./cypress/e2e/utils/Helper");
const csvToJson1 = require('convert-csv-to-json');
const helper = require("csvtojson");


module.exports = defineConfig({
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  watchFileForChanges: false,
  defaultCommandTimeout: 10000,
  pageLoadTimeout: 50000,
  viewportWidth: 1280,
  viewportHeight: 800,
  video: false,
  screenshotOnRunFailure: true,
  "reporter": "mochawesome",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "charts": true,
    "overwrite": false,
    "html": false,
    "json": true,
    "timestamp": 'dd_mm_yy_HH_MM_ss',
    "reportDir": "cypress/reports/mochawesome-report"
  },

  e2e: {
    //To invoke test runner to pick files from the below path
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.js',


    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
      // return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config)
      // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
      // `config` is the resolved Cypress config

      require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config)

      //Start full screen 
      on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
        console.log(launchOptions.args);
        if (browser.family === 'chromium' && browser.name !== 'electron') {
          launchOptions.args.push('--start-fullscreen');
        }
        if (browser.name === 'electron') {
          launchOptions.preferences.fullscreen = true;
        }
        return launchOptions;
      });

      //Convert CSV to JSON
      on('task', {
        csvToJson(data) {
          var lines = data.split("\n");
          var result = [];
          var headers = lines[0].split(",");
          for (var i = 1; i < (lines.length); i++) {
            var obj = {};
            var currentline = lines[i].split(/,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);
            for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
              obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j].replace(/["']/g, "");
            }
            result.push(obj);
          }
          console.log(result);
          return result;
        }
      })

      // Write updated csv data into file
      on('task', {
        finalCsv(updatedJSON) {
          converter.json2csvAsync(updatedJSON).then(updatedCsv => {
            fs.writeFileSync('cypress/fixtures/finalCsvToBeUploaded.csv', updatedCsv);
          }).catch(err => console.log(err));
          return null;
        }
      });

      //For log purpose; prints message in the console
      on('task', {
        log(message) {
          console.log(message);
          return null;
        },
      });

      on('task', {
        updateCsvData({ csvData, finalJsonArray }) {
          let updatedJSON,orderIds = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < (finalJsonArray.length); i++) {
            if ('orderId' in csvData) {
              orderIds[i] = csvData.orderId;
              finalJsonArray[i]['Order ID'] = csvData.orderId;
            }
            else {
              // orderIds[i] = 'OrderId_' + helper.getCurrentDateAndTimeInMiliseconds();
              orderIds[i] = 'OrderId_' + Date.now();
              finalJsonArray[i]['Order ID'] = orderIds[i];
            }

            if ('orderDate' in csvData) {
              finalJsonArray[i]['Order Date'] = csvData.orderDate;
            }
            if ('homebaseExecutionDate' in csvData) {
              finalJsonArray[i]['Homebase Execution Date'] = csvData.homebaseExecutionDate;
            }
            if ('customerExecutionDate' in csvData) {
              finalJsonArray[i]['Customer Execution Date'] = csvData.customerExecutionDate;
            }
          }
          updatedJSON = finalJsonArray;
          return updatedJSON;
        }
      })

      on('task', {
        updateCsvFile(csvData) {
          const finalJsonArray = [];
          let updatedJSON, orderIds = [];

          //readFile
          fs.createReadStream('cypress/fixtures/referenceCsvFile.csv')
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', (data) => finalJsonArray.push(data))
            .on('end', () => {
              console.log(finalJsonArray); // CSV converted to json object

              //Logic to update json objects; for loop to update csv columns in json array
              for (let i = 0; i < (finalJsonArray.length); i++) {
                if ('orderId' in csvData) {
                  orderIds[i] = csvData.orderId;
                  finalJsonArray[i]['Order ID'] = csvData.orderId;
                }
                else {
                  orderIds[i] = 'OrderId_' + this.getCurrentDateAndTimeInMiliseconds();
                  finalJsonArray[i]['Order ID'] = orderIds[i];
                }

                if ('orderDate' in csvData) {
                  finalJsonArray[i]['Order Date'] = csvData.orderDate;
                }
                if ('homebaseExecutionDate' in csvData) {
                  finalJsonArray[i]['Homebase Execution Date'] = csvData.homebaseExecutionDate;
                }
                if ('customerExecutionDate' in csvData) {
                  finalJsonArray[i]['Customer Execution Date'] = csvData.customerExecutionDate;
                }
              }

              updatedJSON = finalJsonArray;
              converter.json2csvAsync(updatedJSON).then(csvFile => {
                fs.writeFileSync('cypress/fixtures/' + fileName, csvFile)
              }).catch(err => console.log(err));
            })
          return orderIds;
        }
      })
      return config;

    }
  }
});
```

In first **it** block, CSV file is updating but when controller comes to second **it** block - considering the same csv file which is updated in first **it** block but I need to update the csv file separately in second **it** block

Comment: Please let us know how you have coded this.

Comment: Added the code for your reference @TesterDick

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the answer to my question:

csvData is an object where column data are stored

```
let csvData = {
            orderDate: getTodaysDate,
            homebaseExecutionDate: getTomorrowsDate,
            customerExecutionDate: getTomorrowsDate
        };
```

Common method to upload the file under commands.js.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('updateCsvFileData', (csvData, referenceFileName, updatedCsvFileName) => {
  cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/' + referenceFileName)
    .then((data) => {
      cy.wait(100).then(() => {
        cy.task('csvToJson', data)
          .then((finalJsonArray) => {
            cy.wait(100).then(() => {
              cy.task('updateCsvData', { csvData, finalJsonArray })
                .then((finalUpdatedJsonArray) => {
                  cy.wait(100).then(() => {
                    cy.task('finalCsv', { finalUpdatedJsonArray, updatedCsvFileName })

                  });
                })
            })
          })
      })
    })
})
```

node.js methods:

```
Convert CSV to JSON object
      on('task', {
        csvToJson(data) {
          var lines = data.split("\n");
          var result = [];
          var headers = lines[0].split(",");
          for (var i = 1; i < (lines.length); i++) {
            var obj = {};
            var currentline = lines[i].split(/,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);
            for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
              obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j].replace(/["']/g, "");
            }
            result.push(obj);
          }
          return result;
        }
      })
```

```
Write updated csv data into CSV file
      on('task', {
        finalCsv({ finalUpdatedJsonArray, updatedCsvFileName }) {
          converter.json2csvAsync(finalUpdatedJsonArray).then(updatedCsv => {
            fs.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/' + updatedCsvFileName, updatedCsv);
          }).catch(err => console.log(err));
          return null;
        }
      });
```

```
Update required fields in CSV file
      on('task', {
        updateCsvData({ csvData, finalJsonArray }) {
          let updatedJSON, orderIds = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < (finalJsonArray.length); i++) {
            if (csvData.hasOwnProperty('orderId')) {
              orderIds[i] = csvData.orderId;
              finalJsonArray[i]['Order ID'] = csvData.orderId;
            }
            else {
              let orderIdRandomNum = Date.now() + "_" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999) + 1);
              orderIds[i] = 'OrderId_' + orderIdRandomNum;
              orders[i] = orderIds[i];
              finalJsonArray[i]['Order ID'] = orderIds[i];
            }

            if ('orderDate' in csvData) {
              finalJsonArray[i]['Order Date'] = csvData.orderDate;
            }

            if ('homebaseExecutionDate' in csvData) {
              finalJsonArray[i]['Homebase Execution Date'] = csvData.homebaseExecutionDate;
            }

            if ('customerExecutionDate' in csvData) {
              finalJsonArray[i]['Customer Execution Date'] = csvData.customerExecutionDate;
            }

            if ('teamId' in csvData) {
              finalJsonArray[i]['Team ID'] = csvData.teamId;
            }

          }
          updatedJSON = finalJsonArray;
          return updatedJSON;
        }
      })
```